Not able to show more than 4-5 bar charts using matplotlib
I am trying to display 4-5 Matplotlib bar chart in a Tkinter window. But some how only 3 are fitting inside the frame. Please find the below code.
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.
# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

fig = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
# fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill='both', expand=True)

fig1 = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
fig1.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
# fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill='both', expand=True)

fig2 = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
fig2.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
# fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill='both', expand=True)


fig3 = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
fig3.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
# fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

canvas3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig3, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas3.draw()
canvas3.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill='both', expand=True)
# toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, frame_top)
# toolbar.update()

# tool = tk.Button(toolbar, text="my tool")
# tool.pack(side='left')#, fill='x', expand=True)


root.mainloop()

I tried to use the horizontal scroll bar, but somehow it is also not working. If there are any other suggestions, or and any other way to show multiple bar charts inside a frame.

You can make the charts smaller or combine them. Also how did you try to add the scrollbar? Why isn't it working?

in your code I see only 3 plots - so where are other plots? Show code which really makes problem.

maybe create only one Figure with 5 subplots. And it may automatically fit all plots in in figure.

code could be shorter and simpler to use if you would use for-loop to create all plots and you would keep them on list - instead of separated variables canvas1,canvas2,canvas3 fig1,fig2,fig3, etc.

maybe use grid() instead of pack() - it allows to set weight for all columns and they should use the same width. OR you have to manually add width to every plot canvas3.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 100 but it may not calculate size automatically

On my Linux helps when I assign any value (event 1) to all canvas' width
canvas.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
canvas1.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
canvas2.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
canvas3.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1


Minimal working code with 10 plots
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

plots = []

for _ in range(10):
    fig = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
    # fig.add_subplot(111).plot(AS)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)
    canvas.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
    plots.append({'fig': fig, 'canvas': canvas})

root.mainloop()

Result:

But it not so useful because all plots are small.

It also works when I put all plots on one canvas
for i in range(10):
    fig.add_subplot(1, 10, i+1).plot(x, y)

But it may not be useful if you plan to add toolbars or move/close some plots.
Full working code:
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

plots = []

fig = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)

for i in range(10):
    line = fig.add_subplot(1, 10, i+1).plot(x, y)
    plots.append(line)

root.mainloop()



Using grid() I had to set correct value for width and height - so I used event <Configure> to do it when it create (or resize) window.
But with grid() I can put it in many rows.
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def resize_widgets(event):
    #print(dir(event))
    print(event.widget, event.width/5, event.height/2)

    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(5):
            widget = plots[(row,col)]['canvas'].get_tk_widget()
            widget['width'] = event.width / 5 
            widget['height'] = event.height / 2 
        
    
# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

plots = {}

for row in range(2):
    for col in range(5):
        fig = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
        #fig.add_subplot(212).plot(x, AS)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=row, column=col)
        #canvas.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 200
        #canvas.get_tk_widget()['height'] = 500
        
        plots[(row,col)] = {'fig': fig, 'canvas': canvas}

frame_top.bind('<Configure>', resize_widgets)

root.mainloop()



Works also when I set weight=1 to every rows and columns in grid() - and it doesn't need <Configure> - so it seems the simplest method.
for row in range(2):
    frame_top.rowconfigure(row, weight=1)

for col in range(5):
    frame_top.columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

Full working code:
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

frame_top = tk.Frame(root)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

plots = {}

for row in range(2):
    frame_top.rowconfigure(row, weight=1)

for col in range(5):
    frame_top.columnconfigure(col, weight=2)

frame_top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # resize first column
frame_top.columnconfigure(4, weight=1) # resize last column

for row in range(2):
    for col in range(5):
        fig = Figure(dpi=100)  # figsize=(10, 6),
        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)
        #fig.add_subplot(212).plot(x, AS)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=row, column=col)
        
        plots[(row,col)] = {'fig': fig, 'canvas': canvas}

root.mainloop()

It allows to set different sizes using proportions - e.g. first and last column 2 times wider.
for col in range(5):
    frame_top.columnconfigure(col, weight=2)

frame_top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_top.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)



Other solution could be putting Frame on tkinter.Canvas and use `Scrollers to move it on canvas - this way plot can be bigger then windows size. But this needs more work - e.g my class  ScrolledFrame on GitHub.

Hi Furas, thanks I am able to show multiple charts now, but I tried similar approach with scroll bar but it is not working. Please find the below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78656980/scrollbar-in-tkinter-is-not-working-with-canvas

if you want to scroll all elements in window then you should put all plots in one tkinter.Frame, and this frame put in tkinter.Canvas and scroll it. But it seems you try to scroll in every plot separately. If you want to scroll data/line in plot then it has own functions to catch mouse event and execute function which will modify data in plot - it has even toolbar which tools to zoom and scroll data.
