Scrollbar in tkinter is not working with canvas
I am new to the python and tkinter, I want to create Dashboard using tkinter. I wrote the below code to add the graphs in tkinter using the Matplotlib. As I have 4 graphs and not able to fit all, so added a horizontal scroll bar but somehow it is not working. Please find the below code.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity):
    if sum_of_demand - allocated < 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = abs(sum_of_demand - allocated)
    elif capacity - sum_of_demand > 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = capacity - sum_of_demand
    else:
        sum_of_not_demanded = 0

    if capacity - allocated > 0:
        spare_capacity = capacity - allocated
    else:
        spare_capacity = 0

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    return sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap


def h_scroll(*args):
    print("In scroll")
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)


def test_gap():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35
    below = np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity])
    above = np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph4_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph4_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
                                         scrollregion=graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().bind("<<Key>>", pop_up)


def graph_three():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66

    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    width = 0.1

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph3_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
                                         scrollregion=graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # mobile_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_two():
    sum_of_demand = 830
    allocated = 313
    capacity = 339
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph2_ax.bar(title, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph2_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
                                         scrollregion=graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # be_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_one():
    sum_of_demand = 1631
    allocated = 778
    capacity = 795
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph1_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph1_canvas.draw()
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
                                         scrollregion=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))

    # horizontal_scrollbar.config(command=h_scroll())


root = tk.Tk()

# Main Frame
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
# Data Frame
graph_frame = ttk.Labelframe(frame, text="Skill Gap")
graph_frame.grid(side = tk.RIGHT, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

horizontal_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(graph_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=h_scroll)
horizontal_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

# Canvas
graph1_fig, graph1_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph1_fig, graph_frame)
horizontal_scrollbar.config(command=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview)
graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)
# Canvas
graph2_fig, graph2_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph2_fig, graph_frame)

# Canvas
graph3_fig, graph_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph3_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph3_fig, graph_frame)

#  Canvas
graph4_fig, graph4_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph4_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph4_fig, graph_frame)

graph_one()
graph_two()
graph_three()
test_gap()
horizontal_scrollbar.config(command=h_scroll)

tk.mainloop()


I am expecting horizontal scroll bar to be work. And able to scroll though all the graphs.

if you want to move all elements then you should put all of them in one tkinter.Frame and put this Frame in tkinter.Canvas and scroll this Frame inside Canvas - but you try to scroll content in FigureCanvasTkAgg. But it may have complex system to keep plot in center. It may  have own function to scroll data in plot - Python - Scroll through Plots - GeeksforGeeks

is it possible to do without Canvas?

you can't. In tkitner Scrollbar works only with Canvas, Listbox, Text but not with Farme. So you have to put frame on canvas and scroll canvas. I already have working example with (short) code from previous question.

Tkitner can scroll only Canvas, Listbox and Text but not Frame
If you want to scroll all elements then you have to put them in one tkinter.Frame and this frame put on tkinter.Canvas and use tkinter.Scrollbar to scroll this frame on canvas.
I took one of my code from answer to your previous question
python - Not able to show more than 4-5 bar charts using matplotlib - Stack Overflow
and I added scrolled cavnas
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def resize(event): 
    dashboard_canvas.configure(scrollregion=dashboard_canvas.bbox('all'))

# --- main ---

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
AS = [10 / 2 ** 0]

# ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

# ---

# canvas
dashboard_canvas = tk.Canvas(root)#, bg='#00c000')  # background color only to test its size
dashboard_inner_frame = tk.Frame(dashboard_canvas)
inner_frame_id = dashboard_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=dashboard_inner_frame, anchor='nw')
dashboard_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# scrollbar
dasboard_scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal')
dasboard_scrollbar_x.pack(fill='x')

# join widgets 
dashboard_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=dasboard_scrollbar_x.set)
dasboard_scrollbar_x['command'] = dashboard_canvas.xview

# resize scrollregion on canvas when plots will have size (and it will be after starting program and drawing plots)
dashboard_inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', resize)

#---

# put on dashboard_inner_frame
frame_top = tk.Frame(dashboard_inner_frame, width=2000)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

plots = []

for index in range(10):
    fig = Figure(dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    fig.suptitle(f"Plot {index+1}")

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)
    #canvas.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
    plots.append({'fig': fig, 'canvas': canvas})

root.mainloop()


Version with code from current question
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# --- functions ---

def resize(event): 
    dashboard_canvas.configure(scrollregion=dashboard_canvas.bbox('all'))


def calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity):
    if sum_of_demand - allocated < 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = abs(sum_of_demand - allocated)
    elif capacity - sum_of_demand > 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = capacity - sum_of_demand
    else:
        sum_of_not_demanded = 0

    if capacity - allocated > 0:
        spare_capacity = capacity - allocated
    else:
        spare_capacity = 0

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    return sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap


def h_scroll(*args):
    print("In scroll")
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview(*args)


def test_gap():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35
    below = np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity])
    above = np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph4_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph4_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().bind("<<Key>>", pop_up)


def graph_three():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66

    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    width = 0.1

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph3_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # mobile_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_two():
    sum_of_demand = 830
    allocated = 313
    capacity = 339
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph2_ax.bar(title, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph2_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # be_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_one():
    sum_of_demand = 1631
    allocated = 778
    capacity = 795
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph1_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph1_canvas.draw()
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))

    # horizontal_scrollbar.config(command=h_scroll())


root = tk.Tk()

# Main Frame
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

# Data Frame
graph_frame = ttk.Labelframe(frame, text="Skill Gap")
graph_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

# ---

# canvas
dashboard_canvas = tk.Canvas(graph_frame)#, bg='#00c000')  # background color only to test its size
dashboard_inner_frame = tk.Frame(dashboard_canvas)
inner_frame_id = dashboard_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=dashboard_inner_frame, anchor='nw')
dashboard_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# scrollbar
dasboard_scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(graph_frame, orient='horizontal')
dasboard_scrollbar_x.pack(fill='x')

# join widgets 
dashboard_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=dasboard_scrollbar_x.set)
dasboard_scrollbar_x['command'] = dashboard_canvas.xview

# resize scrollregion on canvas when plots will have size (and it will be after starting program and drawing plots)
dashboard_inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', resize)

#-----

# Canvas
graph1_fig, graph1_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph1_fig, dashboard_inner_frame)

# Canvas
graph2_fig, graph2_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph2_fig, dashboard_inner_frame)

# Canvas
graph3_fig, graph_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph3_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph3_fig, dashboard_inner_frame)

#  Canvas
graph4_fig, graph4_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph4_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph4_fig, dashboard_inner_frame)

graph_one()
graph_two()
graph_three()
test_gap()

tk.mainloop()

I remove your scrollbar and I put all FigureCanvasTkAgg in the same deskboard_inner_frame and I put deskboard_canvas and deskboard_scrollbar in your label_frame.
To make it more controlled you can keep both desckboard_cavnas and deskboard_scrollbarin one frame (e.g.deskboardordeskboard_outer_frame) and then you have to put only one element in label_frame`

Code is long and it hard to explain - so maybe use tool like Meld to see differences between your version and my version.

I tried this with add two frames (Frame1 and Frame2) but canvas box became really small
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Frame 1")
frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Frame 2")
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP,expand=True)
frame2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,expand=True)
canvas
dashboard_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1)#, bg='#00c000')  # background color only to test its size
dashboard_inner_frame = tk.Frame(dashboard_canvas)
inner_frame_id = dashboard_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=dashboard_inner_frame, anchor='nw')
dashboard_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
Could you please help me

In my use case i need to keep the canvas inside the frame(not the root)

first put all in one frame and later put this frame in canvas. Better put code in question - it will be more readable. And you will have more space to describe problem and to show error messages.

Thanks furas for supporting. I kept the code in the new tread. Please have a look. I tried keep top level frame too but it is also not working as expected.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78658845/canvas-frame-is-small-inside-the-tkinter-frame

meanwhile I made example with your code and I put it in current answer.

Thanks Furas it worked. Thanks for the support.
