Canvas frame is small inside the tkinter frame
I tried to create a frame inside the frame i want place the canvas and inside the canvas one more frame. And inside the frame i want to keep actual canvas and enabled the horizontal scroll. As followed from earlier tread Scrollbar in tkinter is not working with canvas. Canvas block is really small.
`
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# --- functions ---

def calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity):
    if sum_of_demand - allocated < 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = abs(sum_of_demand - allocated)
    elif capacity - sum_of_demand > 0:
        sum_of_not_demanded = capacity - sum_of_demand
    else:
        sum_of_not_demanded = 0

    if capacity - allocated > 0:
        spare_capacity = capacity - allocated
    else:
        spare_capacity = 0

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    return sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap
def test_gap():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35
    below = np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity])
    above = np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph4_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph4_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    # graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
    #                                      scrollregion=graph4_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)
    # test_canvas.get_tk_widget().bind("<<Key>>", pop_up)


def mobile_gap():
    sum_of_demand = 256
    allocated = 73
    capacity = 66

    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    if sum_of_demand - capacity > 0:
        skill_gap = sum_of_demand - capacity
    else:
        skill_gap = 0

    width = 0.1

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph3_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    # graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
    #                                      scrollregion=graph3_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # mobile_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_two():
    sum_of_demand = 830
    allocated = 313
    capacity = 339
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph2_ax.bar(title, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph2_canvas.draw()
    # canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
    graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    # graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
    #                                      scrollregion=graph2_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # be_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)


def graph_one():
    sum_of_demand = 1631
    allocated = 778
    capacity = 795
    sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap = calculate_gap(sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity)

    width = 0.35

    weight_counts = {
        "Below": np.array([sum_of_demand, allocated, capacity]),
        "Above": np.array([sum_of_not_demanded, spare_capacity, skill_gap])
    }
    title = ['Demand', 'Allocated', 'Capacity']

    bottom = np.zeros(3)
    for boolean, weight_count in weight_counts.items():
        p = graph1_ax.bar(title, weight_count, width, label=boolean, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += weight_count

    graph1_canvas.draw()
    graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="left")
    # graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))
    # graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set,
                                         # scrollregion=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"))




def resize(event):
    dashboard_canvas.configure(scrollregion=dashboard_canvas.bbox('all'))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("eggs")

main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack()

# ---
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(main_frame,text="Frame One")
frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(main_frame,text="Frame two")
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True,fill=tk.BOTH)

# canvas
dashboard_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1)#, bg='#00c000')  # background color only to test its size
dashboard_inner_frame = tk.Frame(dashboard_canvas)
inner_frame_id = dashboard_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=dashboard_inner_frame, anchor='nw')
dashboard_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# scrollbar
dasboard_scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal')
dasboard_scrollbar_x.pack(fill='x')

# join widgets
dashboard_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=dasboard_scrollbar_x.set)
dasboard_scrollbar_x['command'] = dashboard_canvas.xview

# resize scrollregion on canvas when plots will have size (and it will be after starting program and drawing plots)
dashboard_inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', resize)

#---

# put on dashboard_inner_frame
frame_top = tk.Frame(dashboard_inner_frame, width=2000)
frame_top.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# dashboard_inner_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# plots = []
graph1_fig, graph1_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph1_fig, frame_top)
# horizontal_scrollbar.config(command=graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().xview)
# graph1_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)
# BE Canvas
graph2_fig, graph2_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph2_fig, frame_top)

# Canvas
graph3_fig, graph_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph3_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph3_fig, frame_top)

#  Canvas
graph4_fig, graph4_ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
graph4_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph4_fig, frame_top)
graph_one()
graph_two()
mobile_gap()
test_gap()

# for index in range(10):
#     fig = Figure(dpi=100)
#     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#     ax.plot(x, y)
#     fig.suptitle(f"Plot {index+1}")
#
#     canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame_top)
#     print(canvas)
#     canvas.draw()
#     canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="left", fill='both', expand=True)
    #canvas.get_tk_widget()['width'] = 1
    # plots.append({'fig': fig, 'canvas': canvas})

root.mainloop()

I wast to have two main frames)Left and Right/Top and Bottom. Inside the Top/Right Frame i want to have canvas with horizontal scroll.

you have to put scrollbar also in frame - tk.Scrollbar(frame1)

if you want to use it in other frames then maybe you should create class with widget (like in code scrolledframe.py) and later use many instances of this class

BTW: there is module Custom Tkinter https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/ which has CtkScrollableFrame (probably it use the same method with canvas but it hides it). And all widgets looks nices

May be you need to configure main_frame to expand to fill all the window space: main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True).
